# Distinguish length from box measures with regex

Tags: regex

I have this regex to capture different info from product name like "Abc 2x200g"

```
\d+\s*x\s*\d*[.,]?\d+\s*(?:cm|g)\b
```

To test: https://regexr.com/69amc

But I have an issue when in the name there are box measures like "Box 20x20x20cm", it captures 20x20cm that's a wrong information for me.

Is there a way to capture what I need but avoid box measure?

Comment: You can append a word boundary at the beginning `\b\d+\s*x\s*\d*[.,]?\d+\s*(?:cm|g)\b` See https://regex101.com/r/00QlfR/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
\b(?<!\dx)\d+\s*x\s*\d*[.,]?\d+\s*(?:cm|g)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/N4IGRa/1/). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!\dx)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a digit + `x` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s*x\s*` - `x` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces on both ends
- `\d*[.,]?\d+` - zero or more digits, and optional `.` or `,` and then one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:cm|g)\b` - `cm` or `g` not followed with any other letter, digit or `_`.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['ABC 2x200g', 'ABC 2x200cm', 'Box 20x20x20cm'];
const re = /\b(?<!\dx)\d+\s*x\s*\d*[.,]?\d+\s*(?:cm|g)\b/;
for (const text of texts) {
  console.log(text, "=>", (text.match(re) || ['No match'])[0]);
}
```